# Get DECIMAL(10,2) in C++ and show it?

Tags: c++, mysql, floating-point, decimal

Have a little problem with decimal data format. So, the code looks like:

```
        #define SHOW_MONEY                    "Money = %.2f!"
        QueryResult result = MyDatabase.PQuery("SELECT money FROM users WHERE user_id = '%u'", GetUserId());

        char str[64];

        Field *fields = result->Fetch();
        float money = fields[0].GetFloat();

        sprintf(str, SHOW_MONEY, money);
        user->ShowInformation(str, GetUserId(), true);
```

And when field contains falues like 12312313.95 it shows 12312314.00 (value is rounded) instead of right value. Is there are any builtin methods to work with decimal data in mysql? I need to get exact value and show it to user. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` is a limited dataformat, and can hold only hold so many bits of information (or `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10` decimal places), in your case just enough for 12312314, but not more information.

As a quick workaround you can try using a `double` or even a `long double`, however you should think about what properties you want your numbers to have. Binary floating point numbers can not even represent numbers like `0.1` precisely (extensive information on this can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)).

Since you are dealing with monetary amonuts, using a decimal floating point library, or a fixed point library, might be the better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`float` is too small a format. Use `double`, or if your compiler supports it, `long double` to get more precision.

However, those floating-point types can't store exact values like 12312313.95. `decimal` is an exact format: it can store the exact value you put into it with the specified precision. Converting to long double will always lose some precision.
The way you're using them now, with `printf("%.2f")` will work fine (it will round the right way), but if you are going to perform extensive calculations on them, maybe it would be better to convert them to `long int` first (by multiplying by 100 and rounding) and only switch back to long doubles when storing them in the database again.